# Loopback filter and include

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

So i have a `model` that has the following relationship:

```
"relations": {
    "member": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "Member",
        "foreignKey": "member_id"
    }
},
```

Now `Member` has a `field` called `email`.

I now want to query all results where the email is set to a specific value:

```
{
    "include": ["member"],
    "where": {"member": {"email": "myemail@hotmail.dk"}}
}
```

However instead of filtering it just returns all results.

Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the result by querying the `model` you defined by querying like this.

```
Model.find({
  include: {
    relation: "member",
    scope: {
      fields: [ email, username, etc ], // define which fields to include in the result
      where: { "email": "myemail@hotmail.dk" }, // only select member with specific email
    }
  }
});
```

In your previous attempt, your `where` clause was not applied to the `member` but to the `model``

Check out the documentation on include filters
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html